# Javascript for Adobe Accrobat .setAction()

Tags: javascript, pdf, parameter-passing, acrobat

In Javascript for Adobe Acrobat there is a method named .setAction (cTrigger, cScript). I want an alert "777" to appear when clicking the text field "Text1":

```
var f = function (){
   var x = 777;
   this.getField("Text1").setAction("MouseUp", "app.alert (x)");
}
```

How to make the local variable x visible in the second parameter cScript? 
Does the phrase (script being a parameter) come from Javascript Core?

Comment: I don't see the context where you would create that kind of function. Just running the function body would be sufficient (with a reasonable trigger).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to assign your value to a string before adding it to setAction

```
var f = function (){
   var x = 777;
   cscript="app.alert ("+ x +")";
   this.getField("Text1").setAction("MouseUp", cscript);
}
```